# Is it possible to use a DC-DC BUCK-BOOSTER instead of a Solar Charge Controller or M.P.P.T in solar Charging?

Tags: solar-charge-controller

DC-DC Buckbooster vs M.P.P.T vs Solar Charger

Comment: No.Because Charcing algorithm is needed while charging a battery.It is not fit into buck converters constant voltage output.

Comment: MPPT is an algorithm. Buck-boost is a switching technology. An MPPT algorithm *can use* whatever switching technology is most useful.

Comment: largely yes, if you only trickle charge or have another charge controller handle the battery details in a safe manner. you would be missing the battery management and max power extraction, but would end up with a a stable output voltage using only a BB DC/DC...

Answer (score 2):

This question is akin to asking "is it possible to use an engine instead of a car or an engine control unit?" - it doesn't make sense as they are components of each other, not alternatives. Your question can't get a meaningful answer.

In fact, a fairly typical solar charge controller will employ a maximum power point tracking (MPPT) algorithm to control a buck-boost DC-DC converter.